# HTML button not calling the function

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to TypeScript/HTML so I don't know a lot about it. I have been trying to call a function using a button, but nothing happens when I click on it. I would really appreciate your help :) Here is my code (It's a form where I can enter a horse's details):

```
<br>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name of Horse*</label>
    <input required ngModel name="name" #name="ngModel" type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!name.valid && name.touched ">Name is required.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description (optional)</label>
    <textarea ngModel name="description" #description="ngModel" type="text" id="description"
              class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday">Birthday*</label>
    <input required ngModel name="birthday" #birthday type="date" id="birthday" class="form-control">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="birthday.valueAsDate > todayDate">Birthday can not be in the future.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Gender*</label>
    <select id="gender" name="gender" ngModel class="form-control" #gender="ngModel" required>
      <option value="{{null}}" (click)="validGender=false;  errorText = errorText + '\n' + 'Please select a gender'; ">
        -- select gender --
      </option>
      <option value="FEMALE" (click)="validGender=true;">Female</option>
      <option value="MALE" (click)="validGender=true;">Male</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="favSport">Favourite Sport (optional)</label>
    <select id="favSport" name="favSport" ngModel class="form-control" #favSport>
      <option value="{{null}}">-- select favourite sport --</option>
      <option *ngFor="let s of sports" value="{{s.id}}">
        {{s.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="mother">Mother (optional)</label>
    <select id="mother" name="mother" ngModel class="form-control" #mother>
      <option value="{{null}}">-- select mother --</option>
      <option *ngFor="let h of horses" value="{{h.id}}">
        {{h.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="favSport">Father (optional)</label>
    <select id="father" name="father" ngModel class="form-control" #father>
      <option value="{{null}}">-- select father --</option>
      <option *ngFor="let h of horses" value="{{h.id}}">
        {{h.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary" Primary routerLink="/horses" rows="5"
          *ngIf="name.valid && name.touched && birthday.valueAsDate<=todayDate && validGender && birthday"
          (click)="addHorse(name.value,description.value, birthday.valueAsDate, gender.value, favSport.value); successPopup(name.value) ">
    Add Horse
  </button>
  <button type="button" onclick="createErrorString()" id="button2" class="btn btn-secondary" Secondary rows="5"
          *ngIf="!name.valid || birthday.valueAsDate>todayDate || !validGender || !birthday">Add Horse
  </button>
</form>
<br>
<b><i>*required</i> </b>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function createErrorString() {

    var errorText = "empty";

    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    if (!name.valid) {
      errorText = errorText + '\n' + "Please enter a name.";
    }

    var birthday = document.getElementById('birthday');
    if (!birthday) {
      errorText + '\n' + "Enter a birthdate that is not in the future.";
    }
    var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
    if (gender.selectedIndex <= 0) {
      errorText = errorText + '\n' + "Select a gender.";
      validGender = false;
    }

    alert("Horse could not be added. Please meet the following requirements: " + errorText);
    console.log("Click");
  }


  var btn = document.getElementById("button2");
  btn.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createErrorString);

</script>
```

This is the whole code. I get the following error on the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createErrorString is not defined

Comment: Can you log `btn` to see what value this variable holds ? Before adding your eventListener, use `console.log(btn)` and check the console in your browser inspector

Comment: You're using Angular (`ngIf=...`). Then also use Angular to add the event handler

Comment: Function is calling but the problem is with "IF condition's".  !birthday, !name.valid

Answer (score 0):

[image: The function is called]The function is called, the isssue is in:

```
 if (!name.valid)
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of null

Comment: There's no element with that id in the shown markup, but this is obviously not the whole markup. And OP would hopefully mention the error from the console if that would be the actual problem.

Comment: I just edited the question. You can see the whole code now. The error is an uncaught reference error: ```createErrorString is not defined```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an event listener HTML has a built-in attribute for buttons.
just use the `onclick` method. for example

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   console.log("Click");
}
</script>
```

one of the previous answers mentioned that something may be wrong with the code. You gave only a piece of your code so their answer is incorrect but could you update your answer with your full code and console logs because the issue may not be the event listener not triggering

Comment: I tried to use ```onclick``` but it still doesn't seem to work :/ I actually also tried other simple code blocks I found from different websites where they also used onclick just to see if those would work and there was still nothing after clicking on the button :(

Comment: So the issue is with some other part of your code

Comment: have you tried using an arrow function? so for example `button.addEventListener('click', () => {// your function code here})`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. But I also noticed that if I use <button ... onclick="function()"> i get the ``function is not defined`` error. But if i use the event listener, nothing even seems to happen..

Comment: seems like it's being called. try just adding a `console.log` to the very start of the function before anything else to see if it's being called if it is there's something wrong with how the function works which would call for a separate question or some independent debugging